# One hundred passwords

Tags: code-challenge, kolmogorov-complexity, source-layout

I have one hundred vaults, each one within another. Each vault has a password, consisting of a single number.

> 95  43  81  89  56  89  57  67  7   45  34  34  78  88  14  40  81  23  26  78  46  8   96  11  28  3   74  6   23  89  54  37  6   99  45  1   45  87  80  12  92  20  49  72  9   92  15  76  13  3   5   32  96  87  38  87  31  10  34  8   57  73  59  33  72  95  80  84  11  4   11  11  37  71  77  91  49  21  52  48  43  11  77  52  64  3   9   21  38  65  69  84  96  78  7   71  80  78  3   97

It's too hard to memorize all these passwords, and it's not safe to keep the passwords on a piece of paper. The only solution I can think of is to use a program with exactly one hundred characters. The password to the `n`th vault will be found by treating the first `n` characters of the code as a program.

Thus, the first character of the program, if run as a program by itself, must output `95`. The first two characters by themselves must output `43`. The entire program must output `97`.

I admit that this is really hard. So just do your best. **Try to make your program work for as many vaults as possible**, and I'll memorize the passwords to the rest.

### Rules

- If there is a tie, the winner is the earliest submission.
- Standard loopholes forbidden. That includes reading from other files or from the Internet.
- You have a few options for the code:

  - A full program which prints the correct number
  - A function which returns or prints it
  - An expression which evaluates to it (e.g. in C, `4+3` evaluates to `7`)
- You *may* assume a REPL environment
- You *may* use different techniques for each value of `n`. For example, you can use different languages for each `n`, or sometimes use a full program and sometimes a function.

*Note: This scenario is completely fictional. If you have a similar issue, do not post your passwords online.*

Comment: Should have used 98 characters... now every single-line submission will *just* cause a horizontal scrollbar. :( ... ;)

Comment: Is there a rule about the length of the program? `The only solution I can think of is to use a program with exactly one hundred characters.` Does this mean every program have to be exactly 100 characters?

Comment: @n̴̖̋h̷͉̃a̷̭̿h̸̡̅ẗ̵̨́d̷̰̀ĥ̷̳ Yes.

Comment: Standard rules allow storing info in filename as long as the bytes are  counted. How here?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

## ><> (Fish), 95

Starting after the `'`  puts all characters onto the stack and at the end of the line it wraps around; closes the string with the same `'`; outputs the top of the stack as a number (`n`) and finish execution (`;`).

Characters for 13 and 10 were changed to space to not ruin the layout of the code (as fish is a 2D language.)

Some non-printable ASCII disappears in the answer. [Correct program here.](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=egvcY2Tc)

```
'n;Y8Y9C-""NX(QN.`JY6%c--WP\1H  \LX `W&WX"9I;!H_PT%GM[140+M4@   &AET`NGPNa
```

Thanks for [Martin Büttner](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/8478/martin-b%C3%BCttner) and [Sp3000](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/21487/sp3000) for improvements of 2 and 5 bytes.

Hex dump:

```
0000000: 276e 3b59 3859 3943 072d 2222 4e58 0e28  'n;Y8Y9C.-""NX.(
0000010: 5117 1a4e 2e08 600b 1c03 4a06 1759 3625  Q..N..`...J..Y6%
0000020: 0663 2d01 2d57 500c 5c14 3148 095c 0f4c  .c-.-WP.\.1H.\.L
0000030: 5803 0520 6057 2657 1f58 2208 3949 3b21  X.. `W&W.X".9I;!
0000040: 485f 5054 0b04 0b0b 2547 4d5b 3115 3430  H_PT....%GM[1.40
0000050: 2b0b 4d34 4003 0915 2641 4554 604e 0747  +.M4@...&AET`N.G
0000060: 504e 0361                                PN.a
```

Comment: Damn this is clever.

Comment: I assume a befunge solution would be a direct transliteration of this?

Comment: @JanDvorak Actually Befunge (even -98) would have more trouble because it doesn't have `'` for string parsing, only `"`, and there are multiple `"`s in the program that would need to be replaced

Comment: I might be the only one here who would have needed help with this, but if you download the file and the ><> interpreter, you can test it using `./fish.py <(head -c 99 raw.php)` where `raw.php` is the name that somehow ended up on the source file I downloaded.

Neat! I can't say I understand it yet...

Comment: Oh wait--reading again, it makes sense now. That's a lot simpler than I thought. Nice!

Answer (score 11):

## CJam, 40

I just used a greedy approach (most of the time) to print the next possible number (carets mark correct program ends):

```
43;56) ; 34 K- 9+ 2* ;11;3Z+;54;6;1 ;80C+K- K+G-;32 6+ 7-Z+;73(  ; 11  60+K+;52;11;64;9;65;7 8;1;8  
 ^  ^ ^   ^^  ^  ^  ^  ^ ^ ^  ^ ^  ^  ^ ^  ^ ^ ^ ^ ^  ^ ^ ^  ^  ^   ^ ^^ ^ ^  ^  ^  ^ ^  ^   ^^^ ^
```

The following numbers are printed correctly:

> 95 **43** 81 89 **56** 89 **57** 67 7 45 **34** **34** 78 88 **14** 40 81 **23** 26 78 **46** 8 96 **11** 28 **3** 74 **6** 23 89 **54** 37 **6** 99 45 **1** 45 87 **80** 12 **92** 20 49 **72** 9 **92** 15 **76** 13 **3** 5 **32** 96 87 **38** 87 **31** 10 **34** 8 57 **73** 59 33 **72** 95 80 84 **11** 4 **11** **11** 37 **71** 77  **91** 49 21 **52** 48 43 **11** 77 52 **64** 3 **9** 21  38 **65** 69 84  96 **78** **7** **71** 80 **78** 3 97

[Test it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/)

Answer (score 8):

## CJam, 56

Here is a somewhat more elaborate approach. It prints the last 56 numbers correctly:

```
0{;"箪⇓ⲩ䏨攛믹Ğᅏꛥ훻ᆾ㼖ꦅ땶읥湓ᠤ䡶"2G#b99bW):W=}:F;FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
```

Chances are, SE has swallowed some characters, [so here's a pastebin](http://pastebin.com/qs1N3LZq). You can try the code [here](http://cjam.aditsu.net/).

It makes use of the fact, that the challenge asks for the programs in characters, so I'm using Unicode characters to encode the last 56 characters in a function, which then leaves the correct element on the stack by incrementing a variable on each invocation and selecting the corresponding element. The rest of the code just calls the function repeatedly.

The first correct program is the one ending at the second `F` in the code. I've fiddled around with the length of characters to be encoded for a while until I hit the right balance to make as much use as possible. One or two more might be possible with this approach.

Answer (score 8):

## (vintage) C - 88

*No need for all these silly dedicated golfing languages. Better go back to the good old days, before the quiche eaters and their "program = algorithm+data" nonsense ruined all the fun.*

The code is a C function, stored as a string.
It returns the binary value as an integer.

Run it in DosBox with Borland Turbo C 2.0.
There are no control characters in the string, so a copy-paste should work.
Compile with **`tiny`** memory model or else...

```
typedef int (* pfun)();
main ()
{
    pfun passwd = (pfun) "¬< sûŠDþ,#ÃEq{1Kt:=qQ+ƒ.?&m):|YH)†P$Pzs/7Tk,2o0&(CƒzIzB-E+\l^Dk‚sw.'..Hjp~T8WSN.pWc&,8Idhwƒq*jsq&„";

    printf ("password %d\n", passwd());
}
```

If you disassemble the start of the string, you'll see something like:

```
scan: lodsb
      cmp al,32
      jae scan
      mov al,[si-2]
      sub al, 35
      ret
```

since `si` is used as function address, it points directly to the code, followed by the passwords.

All values are shifted by 35 to avoid escaping control characters and double quotes.

The code is 11 bytes long, so it will work up to 12 characters.

Unfortunately, the 11th value (34) is too low to produce a valid password with an increased shift value (`ret` opcode is 195, so you would need a shift of 161, and the maximal shift to avoid a rollover is 255-99=156).

11 characters will produce a wrong value, and your virtual PC will experience severe (and usually lethal) undefined behaviours with 10 characters or less.

Answer (score 7):

## Pyth, <s>92</s> 93

```
+_32Ce"c'MBBnx.Hq7:nN(+<#j&7yVE&M!Mwp,|4Qh)|/l-#%@wFw?*B(Yi[Ahpt+$++Egm{Q5TPK+mT`#)5Faetn'gpn#
```

The above code will obviously be messed up because SE removes control characters, so find the actual code [here](http://pastebin.com/9HbiMbUF)

The logic is simple, the string is the character representation of each number, except for the first 3 which are used by the conversion logic and some quotes and newlines which I replaced with dummy characters.

I will try to increase the score here.

[Try it online here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/)

Comment: If you can remove an offset from the printable character at the beginning of your code you can print the 10, 13 an 34's too.

Comment: The program seems to have more than 100 characters, which breaks the rule if I understand the question correctly.

Comment: @n̴̖̋h̷͉̃a̷̭̿h̸̡̅ẗ̵̨́d̷̰̀ĥ̷̳ I think that is just due to copy pasting. Some tab character getting converted to space and likewise.

Comment: @Optimizer: Oh, I see. Can you provide a copy on gist or something? Or a hex dump?

Answer (score 6):

## Matlab <s>37</s> 39

You can use part (without the semicolons) of this idea with any programming language you like, that prints the results directly to console. This will produce at least 39 times the right answers. (I did not check those where only a half number might give a correct answer, but I've found two so far.)

```
43+13+11-33+54;81;78;8+20;74+15-83;01+79-59-12+6-2;;87+0-53+39;72;;11+00+66-56+22;52;3*7+48;78-7+7+0
```

Comment: Sorry, what am I doing wrong? `code="43+13+11-33+54;81;78;8+20;74+15-83;01+79-59-12+6-2;;87+0-53+39;72;;11+00+66-56+22;52;3*7+48;78-7+7+0"; key="95 43 81 89 56 89 57 67 7 45 34 34 78 88 14 40 81 23 26 78 46 8 96 11 28 3 74 6 23 89 54 37 6 99 45 1 45 87 80 12 92 20 49 72 9 92 15 76 13 3 5 32 96 87 38 87 31 10 34 8 57 73 59 33 72 95 80 84 11 4 11 11 37 71 77 91 49 21 52 48 43 11 77 52 64 3 9 21 38 65 69 84 96 78 7 71 80 78 3 97".split(" "); res=0; for(q=0; q<100; ++q) try{ if(eval(code.substr(0,q+1))==key[q]) console.log(++res,q+1,key[q]) } catch(e) {}` - it shows only 28 matches

Comment: And after posting my code and copying it from there result becomes 18 from 28... Are there any nonprintable symbols anywhere? Yes, found them: `&zwnj;&#8203;` after `00+`

Comment: There should not be any nonprintable symbols, but perhaps some of them got sneaked in since it is handtyped. The only symbols used are those fourteen: `012345679+-*;`

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), Score 71

```python
sum(*open(__file__,'br'))%112#M_Q]:D,*i,P(1S#=1fr@g?18[V1bV'at'iwp"v~FTlkPBW|3v|t|^)@yn%^
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NVJRa5xAEH73pe1TSkPpsCGcXjbg6J67CpIQSt8KKSnpg1zEM2sqvaiod83RS//6dfbWguO3zvfNN@PudrvxZ9uEh7J91Clj7DBsnt152@nGzfOqXus857NVP/O8c8Tg7Gv@bZl85vOa37ofT/DuLMWqP71@ukKVvb/Ht6v72Ukxzurf3Qe2/fvl@6f1r9ubH/twu393Or7ZP3jXu@b84UCNMkwucek4Q5rFCw4i5KCQIuawiCaUHCIKegRJQmFDKqIpkNbCt2UBlQeR5YQp5xAToKFoTawkdWSFR29jJo@pOLb@aEFRVpEtBkRRBLQWJJHm26aQZNLYh0drM1tgG5riUE1IhujbmZX9G2nUZBKGk9/C9lLCzjqBCTOcJJSEMdoRAsIFlQllNwwn3uQicZxlUpkZIjKPYmseT3szmZqe0u5LLOkQynbTjJCC71RtDzXUDfRF86Rd9H0vcWDsd/SGMjXXJEvqC3NyAHUFelus3ZL/YebKsGRdPK8ei/lLkq12ox6IYZuxulTMW3L2/0KxhLFXL01hyOql8QXb/yIFJFv9UupuTKArhsHp@roZXXZXtr1OGLdK7/AP)

Note: the code contains unprintable char

Read the code source, and sum all the char value modulo 112 (to include the comment sign `#`. Then adjust each value with the right char in a comment

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2, 39

I wrote a script that tries lots of combinations of expressions, and tests them against the safe combinations. The best I could manage was 39 matches. I was surprised how many combinations resulted in the score of 39. I have included a sample in my answer.

I tried including the logical `^&|` operators but the precedence rules got complicated.

```
43+13+11-33 -20 +9+23-35-8+3+48*0 -5+79-60/7-57-2*5+82+0-53+39 -1+8-76+33+54-39-41*0-43/3+46-6-7*011
43+13+11-33+54/8-14-18+3-8+3+48*0 -5+79-60-11+67-71+82+0-53+39 -1+8-76+7+66-56+22 +9-43/3+46-6-7*011
43+13+11-33 -20 +9+23-35-8+3+48*0 -5+79-60/7-57-2+19 +6-7+3+39 -1+12-73 +66-56+22 +9-43/3+46-6-7*011
43+13+11-33+54/8-14-18+3+63/5+14 +8+0-33+8-11+67-71+82+0-53+39 -1+8-76+33+54-39-9 +9-43/3+46-6-7*011
43+13+11-33 -20 +9+23-35+63/5+14 +8+0-33+8-11+67-71+82+0-53+39 -1+8-76+7+66-56+22 +9-43/3+46-6-7*011
43+13+11-33 -20 +9+23-35+63/5+14 +8+0-33+8-11/2-2+19 +6-7+3+39 -1+8-76+33+54-39-9 +9-43/3+46-6-7*011
43+13+11-33 -20 +9+23-35-8+3+48+45-54-33+8-11/2-2*5+82+0-53+39 -1+12-73 +66-56+22 +9-43/3+46-6-7*011
43+13+11-33 -20 +9+23-35-8+3+48+45-54-33+8-11/2-2+19 +6-7+3+39 -1+8-76+7+66-56+22 +9-43/3+46-6 +2+17
43+13+11-33 -20 +9+23-35-8+3+48*0 -5+79-60/7-57-2*5+82+0-53+39 -1+8-76+33+54-39-9 +9-43/3+46-6-7-681
43+13+11-33 -20 +9+23-35-8+3+48+45-54-33+8-11/2-2*5+82+0-53+39 -1+8-76+7+66-56+22 +9-43/3+46-6 +2+17
43+13+11-33 -20 +9+23-35+63/5+14 +8+0-33+8-11+67-71+82+0-53+39 -1+8-76+7+66-56+22 +9-43/3+46-6 +2+17
43+13+11-33 -20 +9+23-35-8+3+48+45-54-33+8-11/2-2*5+82+0-53+39 -1+8-76+7+66-56+22 +9-43/3+46-6-7*011
43+13+11-33+54/8-14-18+3-8+3+48*0 -5+79-60/7-57-2*5+82-56+3+39 -1+8-76+7+66-56+22 +9-43/3+46-6-7*011
43+13+11-33 -20 +9+23-35+63/5+14 +8+0-33+8-11/2-2+19 +6-7+3+39 -1+12-73 +66-56+22 +9-43/3+46-6-7*011
43+13+11-33 -20 +9+23-35-8+3+48*0 -5+79-60-11+67-71+82+0-53+39 -1+8-76+7+66-56+22 +9-43/3+46-6-7-681
43+13+11-33 -20 +9+23-35-8+3+48*0 -5+79-60/7-57-2+19 +6-7+3+39 -1+12-73 +66-56+22 +9-43/3+46-6 +2+17
43+13+11-33 -20 +9+23-35-8+3+48*0 -5+79-60/7-57-2*5+82+0-53+39 -1+8-76+7+66-56+22 +9-43/3+46-6-7*011
43+13+11-33+54/8-14-18+3-8+3+48*0 -5+79-60/7-57-2*5+82+0-53+39 -1+8-76+7+66-56+22 +9-43/3+46-6-7*011
43+13+11-33 -20 +9+23-35-8+3+48*0 -5+79-60-11+67-71+82-56+3+39 -1+8-76+7+66-56+22 +9-43/3+46-6-7*011
43+13+11-33 -20 +9+23-35+63/5+14 +8+0-33+8-11+67-71+82+0-53+39 -1+8-76+7+66-56+22 +9-43/3+46-6-7-681
43+13+11-33+54/8-14-18+3-8+3+48*0 -5+79-60/7-57-2*5+82+0-53+39 -1+8-76+7+66-56+22 +9-43/3+46-6 +2+17
43+13+11-33 -20 +9+23-35-8+3+48+45-54-33+8-11+67-71+82+0-53+39 -1+8-76+33+54-39-9 +9-43/3+46-6-7*011
43+13+11-33 -20 +9+23-35-8+3+48*0 -5+79-60/7-57-2*5+82-56-23+51+36-84+00+66-56+22 +9-43/3+46-6-7*011
43+13+11-33 -20 +9+23-35-8+20+14 +8+0-33+8-11+67-71+82+0-53+39 -1+8-76+33+54-39-41*0-43/3+46-6-7*011
43+13+11-33 -20 +9+23-35-8+3+48*0 -5+79-60/7-57-2+19 +6-7+3+39 -1+12-73+60-22+3-41*0-43/3+46-6 +2+17
43+13+11-33+54 -7 -35-35-8+3+48*0 -5+79-60/7-57-2*5+82+0-53+39 -1+8-76+33+54-39-41*0-43/3+46-6-7*011
43+13+11-33 -20 +9+23-35+63/5+14 +8+0-33+8-11/2-2*5+82+0-53+39 -1+8-76+7+66-56+22 +9-43/3+46-6 +2+17
43+13+11-33 -20 +9+23-35-8+3+48*0 -5+79-60/7-57-2+19 +6-28+47+2+36-84+00+66-56+22 +9-43/3+46-6-7*011
43+13+11-33 -20 +9+23-35-8+20+14 +8+0-33+8-11+67-71+82+0-53+39 -1+8-76+33+54-39-9 +9-43/3+46-6-7*011
43+13+11-33 -20 +9+23-35-8+3+48*0 -5+79-60/7-57-2+19 +6-28-2+51+36-84+00+66-56+22 +9-43/3+46-6-7*011
43+13+11-33 -20 +9+23-35-8+3+48*0 -5+79-60-11/2-2*5+82+0-53+39 -1+8-76+7+66-56+22 +9-43/3+46-6 +2+17
43+13+11-33 -20 +9+23-35+63/5+14 +8+0-33+8-11/2-2*5+82+0-53+39 -1+8-76+33+54-39-9 +9-43/3+46-6-7-681
43+13+11-33+54 -7 -35-35-8+3+48*0 -5+79-60-11/2-2*5+82+0-53+39 -1+8-76+7+66-56+22 +9-43/3+46-6 +2+17
43+13+11-33+54 -7 -35-35-8+20+14 +8+0-33+8-11/2-2+19 +6-7+3+39 -1+12-73 +66-56+22 +9-43/3+46-6-7*011
43+13+11-33 -20 +9+23-35-8+3+48*0 -5+79-60/7-57-2+19 +6-28-2+51+36-84+00+66-56+22 +9-43/3+46-6 +2+17
43+13+11-33 -20 +9+23-35-8+20+14 +8+0-33+8-11/2-2*5+82-56+3+39 -1+8-76+7+66-56+22 +9-43/3+46-6-7-681
43+13+11-33+54/8-14-18+3-8+3+48*0 -5+79-60/7-57-2*5+82+0-53+39 -1+8-76+33+54-39-9 +9-43/3+46-6 +2+17
43+13+11-33 -20 +9+23-35-8+3+48*0 -5+79-60/7-57-2*5+82+0-53+39 -1+12-73+60-22+3-9 +9-43/3+46-6-7*011
43+13+11-33 -20 +9+23-35-8+3+48*0 -5+79-60-11/2-2*5+82+0-53+39 -1+8-76+33+54-39-9 +9-43/3+46-6-7*011
43+13+11-33 -20 +9+23-35-8+3+48*0 -5+79-60/7-57-2+19 +6-7+3+39 -1+8-76+7+66-56+22 +9-43/3+46-6-7*011
43+13+11-33 -20 +9+23-35-8+3+48+45-54-33+8-11/2-2*5+82+0-53+39 -1+8-76+7+66-56+22 +9-43/3+46-6-7-681
43+13+11-33 -20 +9+23-35-8+3+48*0 -5+79-60/7-57-2*5+82-56+3+39 -1+8-76+7+66-56+22 +9-43/3+46-6-7*011
43+13+11-33 -20 +9+23-35-8+3+48*0 -5+79-60/7-57-2*5+82+0-53+39 -1+8-76+33+54-39-9 +9-43/3+46-6-7*011
43+13+11-33 -20 +9+23-35-8+20+14 +8+0-33+8-11+67-71+82+0-53+39 -1+8-76+7+66-56+22 +9-43/3+46-6-7-681
43+13+11-33 -20 +9+23-35-8+3+48*0 -5+79-60/7-57-2*5+82-56+3+39 -1+8-76+33+54-39-9 +9-43/3+46-6-7-681
43+13+11-33+54/8-14-18+3-8+3+48*0 -5+79-60-11/2-2*5+82+0-53+39 -1+8-76+7+66-56+22 +9-43/3+46-6 +2+17
43+13+11-33 -20 +9+23-35-8+3+48*0 -5+79-60/7-57-2*5+82-56-23+51+36-84+0+60-22+3-9 +9-43/3+46-6-7-681
43+13+11-33+54/8-14-18+3-8+20+14 +8+0-33+8-11/2-2*5+82-56+3+39 -1+8-76+7+66-56+22 +9-43/3+46-6-7*011
43+13+11-33 -20 +9+23-35-8+3+48+45-54-33+8-11/2-2+19 +6-7+3+39 -1+8-76+7+66-56+22 +9-43/3+46-6-7*011
43+13+11-33 -20 +9+23-35-8+3+48+45-54-33+8-11/2-2+19 +6-28-2+51+36-84+0+60-22+3-41*0-43/3+46-6-7*011
43+13+11-33+54 -7 -35-35-8+20+14 +8+0-33+8-11/2-2*5+82+0-53+39 -1+8-76+7+66-56+22 +9-43/3+46-6-7*011
43+13+11-33 -20 +9+23-35-8+20+14 +8+0-33+8-11/2-2*5+82-56+3+39 -1+8-76+33+54-39-9 +9-43/3+46-6-7*011
43+13+11-33 -20 +9+23-35+63/5+14 +8+0-33+8-11/2-2*5+82+0-53+39 -1+8-76+33+54-39-9 +9-43/3+46-6-7*011
43+13+11-33 -20 +9+23-35-8+20+14 +8+0-33+8-11/2-2*5+82+0-53+39 -1+8-76+7+66-56+22 +9-43/3+46-6-7*011
43+13+11-33+54/8-14-18+3-8+3+48*0 -5+79-60-11/2-2*5+82+0-53+39 -1+8-76+33+54-39-9 +9-43/3+46-6-7*011
43+13+11-33 -20 +9+23-35-8+3+48*0 -5+79-60-11/2-2*5+82+0-53+39 -1+8-76+7+66-56+22 +9-43/3+46-6-7-681
43+13+11-33 -20 +9+23-35-8+3+48+45-54-33+8-11/2-2*5+82-56+3+39 -1+8-76+7+66-56+22 +9-43/3+46-6 +2+17
43+13+11-33+54/8-14-18+3-8+3+48*0 -5+79-60/7-57-2*5+82-56-23+51+36-84+00+66-56+22 +9-43/3+46-6-7-681
43+13+11-33 -20 +9+23-35-8+3+48*0 -5+79-60/7-57-2+19 +6-7-23+51+36-84+00+66-56+22 +9-43/3+46-6-7*011
43+13+11-33+54/8-14-18+3-8+3+48*0 -5+79-60-11/2-2+19 +6-7+3+39 -1+8-76+7+66-56+22 +9-43/3+46-6-7-681
43+13+11-33 -20 +9+23-35+63/5+14 +8+0-33+8-11+67-71+82-56+3+39 -1+12-73 +66-56+22 +9-43/3+46-6-7*011
43+13+11-33 -20 +9+23-35+63/5+14 +8+0-33+8-11/2-2*5+82-56-23+51+36-84+00+66-56+22 +9-43/3+46-6-7*011
43+13+11-33 -20 +9+23-35-8+3+48*0 -5+79-60-11/2-2*5+82+0-53+39 -1+12-73 +66-56+22 +9-43/3+46-6-7*011
43+13+11-33 -20 +9+23-35-8+3+48*0 -5+79-60-11/2-2*5+82-56+3+39 -1+12-73 +66-56+22 +9-43/3+46-6-7-681
43+13+11-33+54/8-14-18+3-8+3+48*0 -5+79-60/7-57-2+19 +6-7+3+39 -1+8-76+7+66-56+22 +9-43/3+46-6 +2+17
43+13+11-33 -20 +9+23-35-8+3+48*0 -5+79-60-11/2-2+19 +6-7+3+39 -1+8-76+33+54-39-41*0-43/3+46-6-7*011
43+13+11-33 -20 +9+23-35-8+3+48*0 -5+79-60/7-57-2*5+82+0-53+39 -1+8-76+7+66-56+22 +9-43/3+46-6 +2+17
43+13+11-33 -20 +9+23-35-8+3+48*0 -5+79-60/7-57-2*5+82+0-53+39 -1+12-73+60-22+3-41*0-43/3+46-6-7*011
43+13+11-33 -20 +9+23-35+63/5+14 +8+0-33+8-11/2-2+19 +6-7-23+51+36-84+00+66-56+22 +9-43/3+46-6-7*011
43+13+11-33 -20 +9+23-35-8+3+48*0 -5+79-60/7-57-2*5+82+0-53+39 -1+8-76+33+54-39-41*0-43/3+46-6 +2+17
43+13+11-33 -20 +9+23-35-8+20+14 +8+0-33+8-11/2-2*5+82+0-53+39 -1+8-76+7+66-56+22 +9-43/3+46-6 +2+17
43+13+11-33 -20 +9+23-35-8+3+48*0 -5+79-60/7-57-2+19 +6-7+3+39 -1+8-76+33+54-39-41*0-43/3+46-6-7-681
43+13+11-33+54 -7 -35-35-8+3+48*0 -5+79-60/7-57-2+19 +6-7+3+39 -1+8-76+7+66-56+22 +9-43/3+46-6 +2+17
43+13+11-33 -20 +9+23-35-8+20+14 +8+0-33+8-11/2-2*5+82+0-53+39 -1+12-73+60-22+3-9 +9-43/3+46-6-7*011
43+13+11-33+54 -7 -35-35-8+3+48*0 -5+79-60/7-57-2*5+82+0-53+39 -1+8-76+33+54-39-9 +9-43/3+46-6-7*011
43+13+11-33 -20 +9+23-35-8+3+48*0 -5+79-60/7-57-2*5+82-56-23+51+36-84+0+60-22+3-9 +9-43/3+46-6-7*011
43+13+11-33 -20 +9+23-35-8+3+48*0 -5+79-60/7-57-2*5+82+0-53+39 -1+12-73 +66-56+22 +9-43/3+46-6 +2+17
43+13+11-33+54/8-14-18+3-8+3+48+45-54-33+8-11/2-2*5+82+0-53+39 -1+8-76+7+66-56+22 +9-43/3+46-6 +2+17
43+13+11-33 -20 +9+23-35-8+3+48*0 -5+79-60-11+67-71+82+0-53+39 -1+8-76+7+66-56+22 +9-43/3+46-6-7*011
43+13+11-33+54/8-14-18+3-8+20+14 +8+0-33+8-11/2-2*5+82+0-53+39 -1+8-76+7+66-56+22 +9-43/3+46-6-7*011
43+13+11-33 -20 +9+23-35-8+20+14 +8+0-33+8-11+67-71+82+0-53+39 -1+8-76+7+66-56+22 +9-43/3+46-6-7*011
43+13+11-33 -20 +9+23-35-8+20+14 +8+0-33+8-11/2-2*5+82+0-53+39 -1+8-76+7+66-56+22 +9-43/3+46-6-7-681
43+13+11-33 -20 +9+23-35-8+20+14 +8+0-33+8-11+67-71+82+0-53+39 -1+8-76+7+66-56+22 +9-43/3+46-6 +2+17
43+13+11-33 -20 +9+23-35-8+3+48+45-54-33+8-11/2-2*5+82-56-23+51+36-84+0+60-22+3-9 +9-43/3+46-6 +2+17
43+13+11-33 -20 +9+23-35-8+20+14 +8+0-33+8-11/2-2*5+82+0-53+39 -1+12-73 +66-56+22 +9-43/3+46-6-7*011
43+13+11-33+54/8-14-18+3+63/5+14 +8+0-33+8-11/2-2*5+82+0-53+39 -1+12-73 +66-56+22 +9-43/3+46-6 +2+17
43+13+11-33 -20 +9+23-35-8+3+48*0 -5+79-60-11/2-2*5+82+0-53+39 -1+8-76+7+66-56+22 +9-43/3+46-6-7*011
43+13+11-33 -20 +9+23-35-8+3+48*0 -5+79-60/7-57-2*5+82+0-53+39 -1+8-76+7+66-56+22 +9-43/3+46-6-7-681
43+13+11-33 -20 +9+23-35-8+20+14 +8+0-33+8-11/2-2+19 +6-7+3+39 -1+8-76+33+54-39-9 +9-43/3+46-6-7*011
43+13+11-33 -20 +9+23-35-8+3+48*0 -5+79-60-11/2-2+19 +6-7+3+39 -1+8-76+7+66-56+22 +9-43/3+46-6-7*011
43+13+11-33 -20 +9+23-35-8+3+48*0 -5+79-60/7-57-2*5+82+0-53+39 -1+12-73+60-22+3-9 +9-43/3+46-6-7-681
43+13+11-33 -20 +9+23-35-8+20+14 +8+0-33+8-11/2-2+19 +6-7+3+39 -1+8-76+7+66-56+22 +9-43/3+46-6-7*011
43+13+11-33 -20 +9+23-35-8+20+14 +8+0-33+8-11+67-71+82+0-53+39 -1+12-73 +66-56+22 +9-43/3+46-6-7*011
43+13+11-33 -20 +9+23-35+63/5+14 +8+0-33+8-11+67-71+82+0-53+39 -1+12-73 +66-56+22 +9-43/3+46-6-7*011
43+13+11-33+54 -7 -35-35+63/5+14 +8+0-33+8-11/2-2*5+82-56-23+51+36-84+00+66-56+22 +9-43/3+46-6 +2+17
43+13+11-33+54/8-14-18+3-8+3+48*0 -5+79-60/7-57-2*5+82+0-53+39 -1+12-73+60-22+3-9 +9-43/3+46-6 +2+17
43+13+11-33+54/8-14-18+3-8+3+48+45-54-33+8-11/2-2*5+82+0-53+39 -1+8-76+7+66-56+22 +9-43/3+46-6-7*011
43+13+11-33 -20 +9+23-35-8+3+48*0 -5+79-60/7-57-2*5+82+0-53+39 -1+12-73 +66-56+22 +9-43/3+46-6-7*011
43+13+11-33 -20 +9+23-35-8+3+48*0 -5+79-60/7-57-2*5+82-56+3+39 -1+8-76+7+66-56+22 +9-43/3+46-6-7-681
43+13+11-33 -20 +9+23-35-8+3+48*0 -5+79-60/7-57-2*5+82-56+3+39 -1+8-76+33+54-39-9 +9-43/3+46-6-7*011
43+13+11-33+54/8-14-18+3+63/5+14 +8+0-33+8-11/2-2*5+82-56+3+39 -1+8-76+7+66-56+22 +9-43/3+46-6-7-681
43+13+11-33 -20 +9+23-35+63/5+14 +8+0-33+8-11/2-2*5+82+0-53+39 -1+8-76+7+66-56+22 +9-43/3+46-6-7*011
43+13+11-33+54/8-14-18+3-8+3+48*0 -5+79-60/7-57-2*5+82+0-53+39 -1+8-76+33+54-39-9 +9-43/3+46-6-7*011
43+13+11-33+54/8-14-18+3+63/5+14 +8+0-33+8-11/2-2+19 +6-7+3+39 -1+8-76+7+66-56+22 +9-43/3+46-6-7*011
43+13+11-33 -20 +9+23-35-8+3+48*0 -5+79-60/7-57-2+19 +6-7+3+39 -1+8-76+33+54-39-9 +9-43/3+46-6-7*011
```

Answer (score 0):

## DEBUG.COM, 93

```
0000h: BE FF 00 01 CE AC CC 67 07 45 34 34 78 88 14 40
0010h: 81 23 26 78 46 08 96 11 28 03 74 06 23 89 54 37
0020h: 06 99 45 01 45 87 80 12 92 20 49 72 09 92 15 76
0030h: 13 03 05 32 96 87 38 87 31 10 34 08 57 73 59 33
0040h: 72 95 80 84 11 04 11 11 37 71 77 91 49 21 52 48
0050h: 43 11 77 52 64 03 09 21 38 65 69 84 96 78 07 71
0060h: 80 78 03 97
```

Usage:

```
DEBUG.COM FILENAME.COM
G
```

and the result appears in `AL`